# cURL + Заголовки + Динамическая капча + Ответ

Tags: парсер, curl, captcha

Ребята, спасайте, 3 дня разбираюсь с этой капчей, куками, сессиями , а в ответ всегда одно - wrong captcha.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>
         Парсер ;)
      </title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php
$url = 'https://my.maerskline.com/tracking/search';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
$content = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $content, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
foreach($cookies as $key => $value)
{
    @$cookiee .= $key.'='.$value.';';
}
$cookiee = substr($cookiee,-1);

$content = str_replace('<img class="pull-left captcha-img" src="', '<img class="pull-left captcha-img" src="https://my.maerskline.com', $content);
$content = str_replace('<form action="', '<form action="https://my.maerskline.com', $content);

preg_match('/captcha\?id=[0-9A-Za-z\-]{1,100}/',$content,$matches);
$id = substr($matches[0],11);
preg_match('/captcha\?id=[0-9A-Za-z\-]{1,100}/',$content,$matches);
preg_match('/https:\/\/my.maerskline.com\/captchaapp\/captcha\?id=[0-9A-Za-z\-]{1,100}/',$content,$matches);
?>
    <form action="" method="get">
     <input type="hidden" name="randomID" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
     <input type="text" name="searchNumber" placeholder="Номер"/> 
     <img src="<?php echo $matches[0]; ?>"/>
      <input type="text" name="code" placeholder="Капча"/> 
      <input type="submit" name="send" value="Получить информацию">
      </form>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['send']))
{
$url = 'https://my.maerskline.com/tracking/search?randomID='.$id.'&searchNumber='.$_GET['searchNumber'].'&code='.$_GET['code'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookiee);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $content;
}
?>


   </body>
</html>
```

Самое что интересное если взять ГЕТ строку, которая сгенерировала локалка и вставить ее сюда https://my.maerskline.com/tracking/search
то оно будет работать! 
а если то же самое курлом проделать - то не правильная капча...
Я так понимаю что проблемы в заголовках , куках , сессиях.
Но не понимаю как правильно их спарсить и отправить, что бы точь в точь всё было.
А может в другом проблема ? Натолкните на мысль , пожалуйста.

Comment: Наталкиваю на мысль: вы парсите страницу курлом с собственной сессией и выводите адрес капчи напрямую в браузер, где другая сессия и другой код капчи.

Comment: пробовал курлом же сохранять картинку, всё равно результат 1...

Comment: значит куки не передаются при загрузке картинки и/или передачи формы. в текущем варианте вообще сложно указать на ошибку. постарайтесь оптимизировать код и отделите логику от вывода. так и вам будет проще разобраться в проблеме и людей будет больше, желающих вам помочь.

Comment: спасибо за совет, попробую